# Snackbar in a particular fragment

Tags: android, android-design-library, snackbar

I have 5 sliding tabs in a `ViewPager`, each holding a different fragment. If the data fails to load, I want to notify the user via Snackbar. It's working fine.

What I'm trying to achieve is, if data fails to load in a particular fragment, I want to show a `Snackbar` in that particular fragment only. Is it possible?

> I'll elaborate:

Consider a sliding tab layout with 3 fragments as A, B, & C. All 3 fragments perform some network query and load the data. If due to some reason data fails to load in fragment A, a snackbar should be shown indefinitely. And if the user slides to fragment B (in which data loaded successfully), snackbar should not be visible.

So the snackbar should only be visible in the fragment which failed to load data.

> Fragment Code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/fragment_latest"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
tools:context=".MainFragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/date_layout"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/country_select"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/country"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/month_select"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/month"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
                android:id="@+id/year_select"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:entries="@array/year"
                />

        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/latest_recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/not_available"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

> Snackbar Code:

```
if (Utils.isNetworkAvailable(getActivity())) {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        loadData();
    } else {
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        textView.setText(getString(R.string.check_internet));
        Snackbar.make(frameLayout, "Loading failed.", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Retry", new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadAds();
                refreshData();
            }
        }).show();
    }
```

> where

```
FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.fragment_latest);
```

Comment: **I want to show a snackbar in that particular fragment only. Is it possible?** what do you mean by this ?  You mean when that fragment is visible then only show snakcbar ?

Comment: @NJ I've updated the post with some more details. Please see that.

Comment: while showing snackbar pass view from fragment so when view become invisible then sanckbar automatically become invisible

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't seem to be working. The snackbar is still visible in other fragments as well. Just to let you know, all 3 fragments are new instances of same fragment i.e. **MainFragment** performing some different query based on the value passed to it.

Comment: Please post your code on what you've done so far. It is possible to handle the visibility of your snackbar in the activity handling your fragments, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: post your snackbar showing code

Comment: Updated the post with code.

Comment: frameLayout is varibale from fragment or activity ?

Comment: It is a variable from fragment and the root layout for fragment.

Comment: then refer to the answer i posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you can do is override `setUserVisibleHint` and store snakbar in global variable in fragment when fragment become invisible dismiss the snackbar by using below method

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean visible)
{
    super.setUserVisibleHint(visible);
    if (!visible && snackbar != null ){
       snackbar.dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked! I can now leave for college patiently, thanks. :)